# Does throughput includes CPU idle time also?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

I have 3 processes P1,P2,P3 having gantt chart as follows =>

[image]

Now, CPU remains idle in 0 - 2 sec and 44 - 47 seconds as I/O is taking place.

Does, this affect throughput as 3 processes can be completed in total 47 sec .

Hence, throughput = 3 / 47 .

Is this correct or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct!

According to the defenition Throughput (in case of scheduling in OS) is :

> Number of processes that can be completed in a unit of time.

The process can use both the CPU or the I/O operations. So the I/O time and idle times and CPU time are calculated in throughput.

**Note**: CPU idle time is not calculated when you want to have the Utilization of the CPU. So in your case CPU Utilization is 42/47.

Comment: Number of processes that are completed , means i/o and cpu both should be completed right ?

Comment: @Willturner yes because a process may use both CPU and I/O!

Answer (score 0):

But one more thing I want to add, let say first process is available at 2 units then time period from 0 to 2 will not be considered in CPU total time while computing throughput. As processes are not yet available.

---

Throughput actually includes total time where processes are available and executing doing either computation (in CPU) or I/O.

Comment: (I don't see need to shout at me.) Did the question (or, at that, your answer) *define throughput* or refer to one accessible definition?